# how to use Ajax to get request, Django

Tags: ajax, django

Currently I am loading my html page like as follow-

```
def home(request):
    context = {}
    template = 'home.html'
    return render(request,template,context)

def about(request):
    context = {}
    template = 'about.html'
    return render(request,template,context)
```

If i want to load using ajax then how i request for get. please help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to GET request using ajax::

> from django.shortcuts import render

```
def about(request):
    if request.GET.get('id'):
       data = request.GET.get('id', '')
       template = loader.get_template('YourApp/about.html')
       context = {
        'data': data,
       }
       return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
     url(r'data', views.about, name='about'),
]
```

Path for template should be ::

```
  YourAPP/templates/YourApp/about.html
```

about.html

```
{% if data %}
  {{ data }}
{% endif %}
```

hope, it helps !!

Comment: I am very new to ajax and django , I just put like this
`def about(request):
    if request.GET.get('id'):
       data = request.GET.get('id', '')
       # data = Model.objects.filter()  (Query you want)
       template = loader.get_template('about.html')
       context = {
        'gatdata': data,
       }
       return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))`

but its displaying value error

Comment: I want to load `about.html` using ajax get.

Comment: set your var according to yours requirements

Comment: this is my `about.html` page - 

`{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>hello about</h1>
{% endblock %}`

Comment: Its already set as -  `url(r'^about/$', profiles_views.about, name='about'),`

Comment: check your template path also !!

Comment: try to access by url like ::  `http://localhost:< PORT >/data?id=12345` eg: `http://localhost:8002/data?id=411440`

Comment: I did the same but still getting same error -   `ValueError at /data/`

Comment: what is your template location ??

Comment: This is the location , `profiles/templates/profiles/about.html`

In code I gave as `template = loader.get_template('profiles/about.html')`